# python insert tuple to sql table with executemany pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, executemany

probably I have have a siple error but I have 2 days trying to resolve it.

This is my code:

#insert table
#import pyodbc  #instalar en el prompt de anaconda con pip install pyodbc

#server = 'FERA10\MSSQLSERVER01'
bd = 'DB_Python3'

try:

```
#conexion = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL server}', host = server, database = bd) 
conexion = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',host = server,Trusted_Connection='yes',autocommit=True)
print('Conexión exitosa')
```

except:

```
print('La conexión no fué exitosa')
```

#Creamos un cursor para almacenar la información en memoria
cursor = conexion.cursor()

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO MaratonNY_Python(Corredor INTEGER, place INTEGER, gender VARCHAR(25), age INTEGER, home VARCHAR(255), tiempo FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (Corredor) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", tuplas_lista)

#Guardamos los cambios hechos a la Base de Datos
cursor.commit()

#Nos aseguramos de cerrar la conexión
conexion.close()

But I get this error:

### Conexión exitosa

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[68], line 20
17 #Creamos un cursor para almacenar la información en memoria
18 cursor = conexion.cursor()
---> 20 cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO MaratonNY_Python(Corredor INTEGER, place INTEGER, gender VARCHAR(25), age INTEGER, home VARCHAR(255), tiempo FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (Corredor) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", tuplas_lista)
23 #Guardamos los cambios hechos a la Base de Datos
24 cursor.commit()

ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INTEGER'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Do you know what is my error?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).